# How to control the height of the nav header (or banner)?

Tags: html

I am very new to HTML. I managed to research and learn a basic overview of how to setup the html file, how to insert references...etc. To learn more, I decide to mess around with other HTML projects. Most of them are pretty complex, so I settle on this one from HTML5 Up:  https://html5up.net/read-only. The goal is to mess around and change things up and to learn as I go. I choose this one because it looks the simplest to start messing around.

In the index.html file, the "header nav" is defined like this:

```
            <nav id="nav">
                <ul>
                    
                    <li><a href="#one" class="active">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#two">Things I Can Do</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#three">A Few Accomplishments</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#four">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
```

The "banner" is displayed coded this:

```
<div class="image main" data-position="center">
                                <img src="images/banner.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

As you can see, the banner is slightly shorter than where the "About" selection begin on the right panel. How do I set them to be the same height?

[image]

I tried adding a break in the "banner" defintion, like this:

```
<br>
<div class="image main" data-position="center">
                                        <img src="images/banner.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
```

But that pushes the banner down, you can see the top color is the background of the page, not the banner.
[image]

Is there a way to control them?

Answer (score 0):

Adjust your #header > header padding.

Fullscreen:

[image: FullScreen]

Resized:

[image: Resized]